# How to remove nautilus side bar on some instances

Tags: nautilus, multiple-instances

i want to remove sidebar from nautilus, but not all the time , what i want is to remove it on a certain instance .

the problem is when i remove it on an instance, it's removed from all other instances.

in other words : i want to customize nautilus's sidebar for a specific folders.

how to do that ?

Comment: Please try to give more info next time, If you are using 10.10, do this, View-Side pane, or the hot key F9

Comment: i know that, but this operation affects other instances

Comment: why down-voted ?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are some specifics that can be set in Nautilus. 
Use Alt+F2 and run `gconf-editor` go to > apps > nautilus > preferences > (you can edit a lot of things here)

When done. Exit and restart nautilus by `nautilus -q` the changes will then take effect.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, but i found the problem there.
the problem is that F9 key doesn't just toggle sidebar,it toggles  the key "start_with_sidebar" directly in GConf :(