# Upgraded to 14.04 - can't see system files in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, nautilus

I just upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. Upgrade went smoothly. But some things have changed. I run bare bones Gnome (MetaCity?) and now in Nautilus, I cannot navigate to the file system - can't get out of Home. Even if I call `sudo nautilus` from a terminal it's the same.

In 12.04 I could always navigate to the file system and manage files there with `sudo nautilus`. How do I fix this?

Here is what Nautilus looks like now:

[image]

In 12.04, on the left side of Home was an icon that send me to the file system - no more. I need it back.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what nautilus looks like? Also, try this on command line: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus`

Comment: reinstall did not help. Tnx.

Comment: So your issue is that there used to be a sort of "shortcut" bar on the left, and now it's missing, right? Try looking [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111636/how-to-remove-nautilus-side-bar-on-some-instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right now you are currently seeing this:

[image]

And you want to see these:

[image]

To change it, go to the dropdown arror, and then click `Show Sidebar`.

Or press <kbd>F9</kbd>

Click here to get to the `/` file system.

[image]

You can also run `nautilus /`

Comment: No - this is not the problem, and not the correct answer. Please read again - I'm in a rush at the moment. Thanks

Comment: yes - I need to see the system files